# htaccess redirect from specific urls on home page or on another page?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, post-redirect-get

I read over 20 posts, and I did not find a solution, so in my case I want to redirect `https://example.com/search/` in home page or on another page, but i don't want to redirect `https://example.com/search/?q=query`

Is this possible?

I hope to have a solution.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried, what results did your research yield? Something trivial like https://www.google.com/search?q=mod_rewrite%20how%20to%20check%20the%20query%20string should be able to get you started, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check at the beginning of you search script if the environment variable QUERY_STRING has an empty value.

For instance, in Perl:

```
if ($ENV{QUERY_STRING} eq '') {
{print "Status: 307 Temporary Redirect\n";
 print "Location: https://example.com/\n\n";
 exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help