# Deny Access to index.php File - Apache

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

so I want to restrict access to my index.php file when the request comes with parameters. For example:

https://my-website.com?param1=value1 (Restrict/deny access)

https://my-website.com (Allow access and load website normally)

Is there any way I can do this with a .htaccess file?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to make it in the script itself. If the environment variable QUERY_STRING is not equal to an empty string, display an error message and stop parsing the page, or redirect to the same URL without query string.

You question is opposite to [this one I answered yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51050598).